# Orientdb query child

Tags: sql, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Is there a way with Orientdb 2.1.11 (document database) to get the EmebeddedList

Here is the class structure

```
{
    "@class":"Quote",
    "number":"Q1",
    "details":[{
      "code":"123",
      "price":10
      },{
      "code":"456",
      "price":20
      }
    ]
},{
    "@class":"Quote",
    "number":"Q2",
    "details":[{
      "code":"789",
      "price":15
      },{
      "code":"951",
      "price":25
      }
    ]
}
```

I would like a query that will return the following :

```
number| code | price
------|------|------
Q1    | 123  | 10
Q1    | 456  | 20
Q2    | 789  | 15
Q2    | 951  | 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your structure

[image]

and I have used this query

```
select number, details.code as code, details.price as price from (select prop.number as number, prop.details as details from (select prop from test unwind prop) unwind details)
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for pointing `unwind` in you answer. Turns out that was the life saver. `select from quote unwind details`